# How to install rabbitmq-plugins tool?

Tags: rabbitmq

[This](http://www.rabbitmq.com/plugins.html) page tells me what I can do with the rabbitmq plugins tool. But I can't figure out how to install the plugins tool itself. I just seem to have rabbitmq-server and rabbitmqctl. The [man pages](http://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmq-plugins.1.man.html) doesn't say anything either. So how do I install it? I currently have {rabbit,"RabbitMQ","2.6.1"} running  and I didn't install the server so I don't know how it was installed.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the plugin tool was introduced from 2.7 onwards. For 2.6.1, I assume we need to copy the plugin files to the plugins folder. Unless someone can confirm otherwise.